# Using sp_MSForEachTable with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to write a function to get the sizes for tables in a database. I know the caveats about sp_MSForEachTable, but I think this is an appropriate use for it. This is my code currently:

```
            SqlCommand dbTableSizes = new SqlCommand("sp_MSForEachTable", Conn);
            dbTableSizes.Parameters.AddWithValue("@command1", "'exec sp_spaceused \"?\"'");
            dbTableSizes.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataReader dbTableSizeReader = dbTableSizes.ExecuteReader();
```

However, I get an "Incorrect syntax" exception for every table. The brackets and quotes are in the right place, and `exec sp_MSForEachTable 'exec sp_spaceused "?"'` works (ase expected) when I run it in SSMS. So what is going on? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The value of the parameter proper is `exec sp_spaceused "?"`; the single quotes only delimit the literal when passed as part of the statement. (Note that since `sp_msforeachtable` returns multiple result sets, you'll need `.NextResult` as well as `.Read`, which is unusual.)

Comment: Since this is nothing but a cursor behind the scenes why not just roll your own instead? Undocumented procedures being used in code is always touch and go.

Comment: I'm running this for a bunch of databases in sequence (and this could be repeated with even more DBs down the road) and I didn't want to set up a new SP for each database. And I also didn't want to have a lot of back and forth between my application our of fear it would look messy. Maybe I'm being irrational about these things. :)

Comment: But thanks for your comment. If there's a link you can provide for reference I would be happy to learn.

Comment: I mean that you could roll your own logic with dynamic sql and loop through all the tables found in sys.tables.

Answer (score 1):

This worked calling sp_MSforeachtable:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_MSforeachtable @command1='EXEC sp_spaceused ''?'''", con);
con.Open();
using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (dr.Read())
  {
   
    Console.Writeline("Name: " + dr.GetString(0));
    Console.Writeline("Rows: " + dr.GetString(1));
    Console.Writeline("Reserved: " + dr.GetString(2));
    Console.Writeline("Data: " + dr.GetString(3));
    Console.Writeline("IndexSize: " + dr.GetString(4));
    Console.Writeline("Unused: " + dr.GetString(5));
   dr.NextResult();
  }
}
```